# How can I run a py2exe program in windows without the terminal?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

Could someone explain to me how can I run my py2exe program, a console program, without the terminal on Windows?

I'm trying to make a program that re-sizes windows and it supposed to start with windows, so I want it hide out but still running...

Comment: I edited your question. The program always runs in the background, but you can spawn it without the terminal window.

Comment: thx for the edit... I'm not even to good on english, and its kinda hard express myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `setup()` function like this:

`setup(windows=['myfile.py'])`

See the [list of options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) for `setup()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really understand your requirement, but you can try `start /MIN`. type `start /?` on the command line to see its help page.

Comment: I want my program running in background, or, showing the process only on ALT TAB DEL

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider compiling it into an EXE (using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or some such) and adding it to your list of startup programs?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is for your script to run as a Windows Service instead of a Windows program. Something like this tutorial might be helpful:

http://islascruz.org/html/index.php?gadget=StaticPage&action=Page&id=6